# Framework for UI management - Design improvement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, singleton, service-locator

I am in the middle of writing a small structure to serve as a framework for handling the 2D GUI of a Unity3d project. I have one empty gameobject called "UIManager" with "UIManager" script on it. UIManager is a [Singleton](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) with [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html). Now here is a problem, it works for all practical purposes but design wise, i am openly revealing my implementation (that it is a singleton) to the rest of the world/project. I need suggestion on how it could be improved such that it is better encapsulated.

For a better design of the problem, I stumbled upon [Service Locator Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx). Now I am even more confused. If i am understanding it correctly, I still declare my UIManager as singleton, but instead of getting it's reference via something like UIManager.GetInstance()... I create another Singleton of "ServiceLocator" and ask it for an instance of UIManager. I don't see how it improves the encapsulation of my UIManager class, whose implementation still remains public. And I don't see how it helps with decoupling.

Any insight into the issue? How do you prefer to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve the access, then remove the public static reference. If you need it because your framework depends on it then maybe it is meant to be public.

You can also make your project a full assembly so your public member can be internal and only accessible from within the assembly.

You could also have your object to use interface to minimize the content accessible.

```
public interface IFirst{ void GetFirstThing(); }
public interface ISecond { void GetSecondThing(); }
public class MyClass:MonoBehaviour, IFirst, ISecond
{
    public void GetFirstThing(){}
    public void GetSecondThing(){}
}

public class ConsumerForFirstOnly
{
    private IFirst first = null;
    public ConsumerForFirstOnly(IFirst first)
    {
        this.first = first;
    }
}
```

Now your ConsumerForFirstOnly is not aware of the ISecond part of the class.

Comment: Oh, so you mean that I divide the functionality of the Manager class into interfaces, and return the static shared object as reference to the required interface? So I could separate the Manager into say ILoader and IDestructor, for loading and destroying Canvases respectively? Thats neat! Is there a name given to this approach of hiding internal implementation? Like a pattern or something? Wondering how much is it different from simplest form of abstraction like property getters etc...

Comment: I dont know any naming for this. It's basically the essence of interfaces. If no naming put yours on. It also allows you to break your manager class without changing all your framework. Say you decide the ILoader to be implemented elsewhere, remove the part from the Manager and set it elsewhere. The consumer classes wont see the different. You can also come up with a Factory where a parameter could define which ILoader to use if you had many. This without changing the consuming classes.

Comment: Yes, it is infact a simple use of interfaces. However, the more I think about it, it seems less and less useful in my case. First, I feel that loading and destruction would be happening together in most cases, and everywhere I would need to get two references, ILoader and IDestructor. Next, i will be consuming space on vtable, I remember when much use of interfaces led to 'run out of trampolines' exception. And I cant foresee any other class making use of those interfaces, which mainly throws away the beauty of interfaces. And lastly, two extra classes and method signature duplication.

Comment: In your case, loading and destruction should indeed be the same interface as they server the same purpose. I feel in your case, you want to use internal and assembly. You would create a new dll, add a reference to your project, add the namespace. Now public is available but internal is not visible. Still, internal is visible within your own assembly. As a result, you expose only what you feel relevant and you can keep the manager internal and none accessible.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. Thanks.